# What is Resolve?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

In PvP matches there is a special “Resolve” meter. It seems to fill up during fights and then it slowly goes down. How exactly does it work? What does it affect?

[image: The Resolve meter]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Resolve is a system to counter crowd control (CC) abilities in PvP. This meter builds up as more CC is put upon you, when it reaches a certain point this allows the player to be Resolved in his motives and he becomes immune to CC for 8 seconds. This meter is viewable by anyone. So you have to be careful to see that your opponent doesn't have a near full or full resolve meter.

This allows for heavy CC builds to be used in their full extent in PvP.

Comment: And more importantly, it ensures that heavy CC builds don't dominate PvP to the exclusion of anything else.

Answer (score 2):

When it is full, you can become immune to CC (crowd control) - stuns etc. It is filled by being subject to CC. The idea is to prevent people from spending too much time CC'd, however in practice you're not likely to see it fill without you or your opponent being dead.

Comment: Happens a lot in Huttball actually. Say a Juggernaught tank grabs the ball, uses a lot of area taunt, has a healer on him. He can live forever even with the whole other team focused on killing him. Once resolve fills up he can just wade to the goal line.

Answer (score 0):

A full resolve meter allows you to, in WoW parlance, "trinket" to break CC effects that are currently on you.

You gain resolve through being hit with negative effects, and when hit by enough, you're able to then break free of some, ostensibly balancing the more debilitating PvE skills for PvP.

Comment: It is more like diminishing returns than a trinket when comparing it to WoW.